# Export Import Oracle SQL Data with MetaData

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv, import-from-csv

I am trying to export some data from a connection say UAT to DEV. Once I export my data into a new table, would do a MINUS to get the missing or incorrect data. I don't have the option of creating a dblink.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM NEWLYIMPORTED_TABLE;
```

I am able to export the data and import it to a new table. However, the MINUS does not work since the table metadata is not exported. Is there an option to export/import table metadata (as in column's properties besides the column name) to be able to do MINUS.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 19.2

Comment: since it's dev, why not just nuke it, and re-create it from scratch with a data pump export of your source instance?